# Localization of a SQL Server 2012 table to japanese language

Tags: localization, sql-server-2012

I have a table called country that will store all the country related details in it. Below is the screenshot of my country table.

[image: Country Table]

I want to localize this table to Japanese language. I googled out and found out that a new table needs to be created for storing the data in localized language.

If that's the case do we need to manually translate the text in the country table for each and every country?

Is there any automated process for that? Just like not translating the text manually for each and every rows..

This is because I have few more tables in which the text are not static. they will get loaded on a daily basis. So I will not be able to translate them every day..

Comment: If you want to use Japanese, you should use the `nvarchar` datatype (instead of `varchar`) for your string column to store them as Unicode (and thus preserve the Japanese characters)

Comment: Yeah.. I will have a nvarchar datatype in my localized table for all the columns...

Comment: Can anyone let me know how to achieve this